# Manage Calendar Events

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to automate one of my email address calendar app using script When an event booked it should automatically accept the event and if the event is already booked then reject the event and send an email notification.

Below Script is not working, please help me to fix the issue.

```js
function processInvites() {
  var calendarId =  'myemail@domain.com'; // this needs to be the email address of the calendar you're monitoring
  var invited = "INVITED";
  var accepted = "YES";
  var accept = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES;
  var reject = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO;
  var rejection = "Eep - someone else has a booking then..."; //subject line for our email to reject a booking
  
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);
  
  var start = new Date();
 // var end = new Date("January 1, 2100 00:00:00 IST");
  var end = new Date ("January 1, 2100 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)")
  var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end, invited); //find all future invites (up to 2099)
  
  for(var i = 0; i < invites.length; i++){
    Logger.log("Processing: "+invites[i].getTitle());
    //Search for accepted events that overlap this one:
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(invites[i].getStartTime(), invites[i].getEndTime(),accepted);
    if(conflicts.length>0){
      Logger.log("Found a potential conflict to: " + invites[i].getTitle());
      Logger.log("Creator is: " + invites[i].getCreators());
      var body = 
            "Hi "+invites[i].getCreators()+",<br><br>"+
            "You tried to make a booking, between:<br><br>"+
            "<b>"+invites[i].getStartTime()+"</b>"+
            "<br>and<br><b>"+
            invites[i].getEndTime()+"</b><br><br>"+
            "Unfortunately it's already booked then by <b>"+conflicts[0].getCreators()+"</b> for <b>'"+conflicts[0].getTitle()+"'</b><br><br>"+
            "Sorry!";
      MailApp.sendEmail(invites[i].getCreators(), rejection, "", {htmlBody: body})       
      invites[i].setMyStatus(reject);
    }
    else{
      Logger.log("No conflict, accepting: " + invites[i].getTitle());
      invites[i].setMyStatus(accept);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Little more details as to what is not working or what error you get while running this code would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Jack, I am not getting any error but code is not creating the event or deleting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code for getEvents returns no events, (More details at the end)

```
var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end, invited);
```

So this my workaround to determine events you are invited/accepted

```
var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end)//,{ search : "bday"});
for (var i = 0; i<invites.length; i++){
 if(invites[i].getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED)  // for accepted use CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES
  Logger.log(invites[i].getTitle()) 
}
```

**Note:** If your the owner of the event though this will not work

Your final code will look something like this(Untested Code):

```
function processInvites() {
  var calendarId =  'myemail@domain.com'; // this needs to be the email address of the calendar you're monitoring
  var invited = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED;
  var accepted = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES;
  var accept = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES;
  var reject = CalendarApp.GuestStatus.NO;
  var rejection = "Eep - someone else has a booking then..."; //subject line for our email to reject a booking

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarId);

  var start = new Date();
 // var end = new Date("January 1, 2100 00:00:00 IST");
  var end = new Date ("January 1, 2100 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)")
  var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end); //find all future invites (up to 2099)

  for(var i = 0; i < invites.length; i++){
    if ( invites[i].getMyStatus() != CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED){
       continue;
    }
    Logger.log("Processing: "+invites[i].getTitle());
    //Search for accepted events that overlap this one:
    var conflicts = calendar.getEvents(invites[i].getStartTime(), invites[i].getEndTime());
    for (var j = 0; j < conflicts.length ; j++){
       if(conflicts[j].getMyStatus() == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES)
             break;
    }
    if(j < conflicts.length){
      Logger.log("Found a potential conflict to: " + invites[i].getTitle());
      Logger.log("Creator is: " + invites[i].getCreators());
      var body = 
            "Hi "+invites[i].getCreators()+",<br><br>"+
            "You tried to make a booking, between:<br><br>"+
            "<b>"+invites[i].getStartTime()+"</b>"+
            "<br>and<br><b>"+
            invites[i].getEndTime()+"</b><br><br>"+
            "Unfortunately it's already booked then by <b>"+conflicts[j].getCreators()+"</b> for <b>'"+conflicts[j].getTitle()+"'</b><br><br>"+
            "Sorry!";
      MailApp.sendEmail(invites[i].getCreators(), rejection, "", {htmlBody: body})       
      invites[i].setMyStatus(reject);
    }
    else{
      Logger.log("No conflict, accepting: " + invites[i].getTitle());
      invites[i].setMyStatus(accept);
    }
  }
};
```

Additional Details: 
According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date,Object)), the syntax for getEvents with filters should be something like this:

```
var invites = calendar.getEvents(start, end, {statusFilters : [CalendarApp.GuestStatus.INVITED]})
```

However, this gives an empty invite list as well, in my case (My syntax could be wrong as well, my searches on the same came up empty).

Comment: HI Jack, Thanks for the response ...
Yes, able to list the events and event accept is working perfectly fine, however, the in Conflict event I am getting error 
Line 24(       if(conflicts[i].getMyStatus == CalendarApp.GuestStatus.YES))
"GuestStatus Not defined"

Comment: That is typo, it is supposed to be `conflicts[i].getMyStatus()` and not `conflicts[i].getMyStatus`.. it is fixed now

Comment: Jack Brown, I have replaced conflicts[i].getMyStatus() but still facing same error, can you please review

Comment: should be fixed now, please check.